# SSIS OLEDB Command fails - unknown error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012, oledbcommand

I keep getting an unexplainable error (see below) when I try to run a simple query in SSIS' OLEDB Command.

My query runs just fine in SQL Server, I made some adjustments to make it simpler to ensure it runs, but to no avail.

```
DECLARE @Gender [nvarchar](6)
DECLARE @Ready [nvarchar](12)
DECLARE @DOB [datetime]

SET @Gender=?
SET @Ready=?
SET @DOB=?


IF @Gender = 'M'
    SET @Gender='Male'
IF  @Gender = 'F'
    SET @Gender='Female'
IF @Ready='Y'
    SET @DOB=NULL

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PHI_CLIENT_PROFILES]
([col43],
[col13],
[col22],
[col10],
[origin]
)
VALUES
(@DOB, @Gender, ?, ?, ?)
```

*ERROR MESSAGE:*

> Validation error. Data Flow Task: Data Flow Task: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code:
>   0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB
>   Provider for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Syntax
>   error or access violation"

Comment: Are you providing 7 variables on the parameter mapping tab?

Comment: @billinkc no I am not because of that error, the param page will *NOT* refresh. I tried 100 different varaitions, and added/removed my code line by line so the param page is outdated (it shows 1 param because of my line by line approach). Previous to breaking the code, the param page wouldn't show anything

Comment: @billinkc I should also add that the issue seems to be over the variable part. Does SSIS OLEDB COMMAN accept variables? I tried a simpler code  and it worked, but I'm quite new to this task.

Comment: I would start by replacing all parameters by actual values and see if this executes, then restore them one-by-one, to see if it is a specific parameter which creates the problem.

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis Thanks for the advice. I did just that , but unfortuantely the only way it'd work is to get rid of ALL DECLAREs and SETs. I am fairly sure I had used DECLARE/SET before in a simpler case though - but it doesn't work here for some reason

Comment: I even have an example here that mentions it should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313388/can-variable-define-in-ole-db-command

Comment: Rereading this. You specify OLE DB Command. There are 3 things in SSIS that get mixed up - Execute SQL Task, OLE DB Source and OLE DB Command but they all have very different purposes. To verify, you have the above script in an `OLE DB Command` which sits inside a data flow, yeah?

Comment: @billinkc . Yes, you are correct (sorry about the confusion). I am using the OLE DB Command in a data flow and really using it as somewhat of a destination (I'm running INSERT commands using it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you are intending there, but unless you need the inserted identities or calling some legacy function, there is no need for the **`OLE DB Command`**. Using this transformation for executing only SQL insert statements to a single table should be avoided as it will execute each row as separate batch. Try a destination component instead.

Add a **`derived column`** component and use built-in expression functionality. Example:

```
DerivedGender :    
    [Gender] == "M" ? "Male" : "Female"
DerivedDOB :
    [Ready] == "Y" ? NULL(DT_DBTIMESTAMP) : [DOB]
...
```

After doing the transformation, use an OLE DB destination component.

In some cases, it might be worth to check whether the **`Foreach Loop Container`** can solve the task.

Comment: Thank you so much - I was actually unaware of the use of this task.

Comment: Just one thing though, your case is inaccurate: If Gender is M then Male, if Gender is F then female (there is no else), how could you express that?? Thank you

Comment: `[Gender] == "M" ? "Male" : [Gender] == "F" ? "Female" : "Invalid"`